# How to solve Conflicting getter definitions for property in jackson

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I have some model classes.

```
public interface Product extends Serializable {
    public Sku getDefaultSku();

   public void setDefaultSku(Sku defaultSku);
}

public interface Sku extends Serializable {
     public Boolean isTaxable();

    public Boolean getTaxable();

    public void setTaxable(Boolean taxable);
}

public interface PremiumProduct extends Product {
   public Long getProductCode();

   public void setProductCode(Long productCode);
}
```

Product and Sku implementations cannot be modified. I only extend from Product. After that, I transfer JSON object from spring MVC controller. 
My controller method is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/productDetail", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Product getCustomerName(@RequestParam String productUrl) throws Exception {

      Product product = catalogService.findProductByURI(productUrl);      

                return product;
    }
```

I got following exceptions.

```
<h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /productDetail. Reason:
<pre>    Conflicting getter definitions for property "taxable":

org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.SkuImpl#getTaxable(0 params) vs org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.SkuImpl#isTaxable(0 params)
(through reference chain: com.yoma.product.PremiumProductImpl["defaultSku"])</pre></p>

<h3>Caused by:</h3>
<pre>org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "taxable":
org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.SkuImpl#getTaxable(0 params) vs
org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.SkuImpl#isTaxable(0 params)
(through reference chain: com.yoma.product.PremiumProductImpl["defaultSku"])
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:740)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:39)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._findAndAddDynamic(BeanPropertyWriter.java:463)

   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:441)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2566)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2088)
   at com.yoma.controller.catalog.ProductController.getCustomerName(ProductController.java:69)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:643)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.cms.web.URLHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(URLHandlerFilter.java:74)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.security.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilter(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:90)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.order.security.CartStateFilter.doFilter(CartStateFilter.java:86)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.security.CustomerStateFilter.doFilter(CustomerStateFilter.java:147)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.common.security.handler.CsrfFilter.doFilter(CsrfFilter.java:83)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.BroadleafRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(BroadleafRequestFilter.java:146)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:448)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1067)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:377)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1001)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:360)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)

   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:622)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "taxable":
org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.SkuImpl#getTaxable(0 params) vs
org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.SkuImpl#isTaxable(0 params)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getGetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:162)

   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getAccessor(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:111)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.removeIgnorableTypes(BeanSerializerFactory.java:701)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanProperties(BeanSerializerFactory.java:558)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.constructBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:430)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:343)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:287)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:735)
   ... 98 more
</pre>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "taxable": org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.SkuImpl#getTaxable(0 params) vs org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.SkuImpl#isTaxable(0 params)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getGetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:162)

   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getAccessor(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:111)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.removeIgnorableTypes(BeanSerializerFactory.java:701)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanProperties(BeanSerializerFactory.java:558)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.constructBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:430)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.findBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:343)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:287)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:735)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:39)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._findAndAddDynamic(BeanPropertyWriter.java:463)

   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:441)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2566)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2088)
   at com.yoma.controller.catalog.ProductController.getCustomerName(ProductController.java:69)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:643)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1331)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.cms.web.URLHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(URLHandlerFilter.java:74)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.security.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilter(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:90)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.order.security.CartStateFilter.doFilter(CartStateFilter.java:86)

   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.security.CustomerStateFilter.doFilter(CustomerStateFilter.java:147)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.common.security.handler.CsrfFilter.doFilter(CsrfFilter.java:83)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.BroadleafRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(BroadleafRequestFilter.java:146)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1302)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:448)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1067)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:377)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1001)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:360)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)

   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:622)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
</pre>
```

So, how can I get my JSON from my controller.

Answer (score 33):

You can try to ignore `isTaxable()` for example to solve the conflict:

```
@JsonIgnore
public Boolean isTaxable();
```

Comment: What if you don't have access to the source?  Like an object from a third party lib.

Comment: Is there not a way to have both properties, setting a different property name for isTaxable()?

Comment: could someone explain why this issue is happening?

Answer (score 9):

My problem is ok by folllowing solution according to the Programmer Bruce's answer.

I wrote MixIn class,

```
abstract class IgnoreSetValueMixIn {    
  @JsonIgnore public abstract Boolean getTaxable();
  @JsonIgnore public abstract Boolean isTaxable();
  @JsonManagedReference  public abstract Sku getDefaultSku();
  @JsonBackReference public abstract Product getDefaultProduct();
}
```

In controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/productDetail", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getCustomerName(@RequestParam String productUrl, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Sku.class, IgnoreSetValueMixIn.class);
            mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(SkuImpl.class, IgnoreSetValueMixIn.class);

return mapper.writeValueAsString(product);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> Product and Sku implementations cannot modifie.

[Jackson Mix-In Annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) to the rescue!

Comment: Yap, I am ok with Mix-in annotaitons solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/) lib. To enable it in spring you need to register the message converter and then everything should work.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="com.owlike.genson.ext.spring.GensonMessageConverter"/>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```